# report result of two stage of tsls regression in R

Tags: r

I have a tsls regression and I want to see result of each stage separately and simultaneously. I can't find any command for this in R, but I know that this command is available in other software like Stata. Is there any command in R too?

Answer (score 0):

It is odd that there is not a readily apparent way to ask `tslt()` to do just what you say, nor are the first stage results apparent in the return values.

However, you could simply get the least squares model of your instrument(s) first. Using the first example from the `tsls()` documentation:

```
# First stage
lm(P ~ D + F + A, data=Kmenta)
summary(lm(P ~ D + F + A, data=Kmenta))

# Second stage
tsls(Q ~ P + D, ~ D + F + A, data=Kmenta)
summary(tsls(Q ~ P + D, ~ D + F + A, data=Kmenta))
```

I suppose that if you wanted to do this with a single command you could wrap that all up in a function to do so pretty easily.